# How to transfer podcasts from one computer to another?

Tags: banshee, podcast

I have 6 GB worth Podcasts on my Old computer and I wish to transfer to to my new computer? I know where my podcasts files are stored. How do I copy it to my new computer such that the old podcasts are read and keep adding episodes later? All of this on Banshee Media Player. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I should combine your two questions, as the other one is very similar http://askubuntu.com/questions/189900/how-to-move-podcasts